# Ubuntu won't install from Live CD

Tags: installation, live-cd

Complete noob here. I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a Live CD. I told the computer to boot from the CD (it does) & it reads the CD & then quits with the Ubuntu dots just freezing. I checked the disk & did the memory test, both OK. I also did the nomodeset in the start-up line. Hit escape when it froze but there were no msgs. Have also tried Ubuntu 12.10 & Dream Studio, same thing.

Connected the other disks (WD Raptor, Maxtor 250 GB), no change. The reason I did that was because now my computer looks for drives, can't find any & quits. Now it finds drives but still doesn't work. It has an Intel SSD, which I intend to be C: I don't know if you have to format SSDs or not but I don't think so. I have a Samsung 830 on this computer w Windows & I didn't have to format it. I also tried installing with a Ubuntu Studio DVD which I burned @ single speed, as I had seen some warnings about disks burned faster but still no-go. This machine ran fine when it had Windows & I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't do Ubuntu.

Anyone have any ideas?

- ASUS P5E3, 3 GHz chip, 4 GB ram, EVGA Force 8800 GTX video, Intel SSD.

---

Tried some other stuff today. Connected the other disks (WD Raptor, Maxtor 250 GB), no change. The reason I did that was because now my computer looks for drives, can't find any & quits. Now it finds drives but still doesn't work. It has an Intel SSD, which I intend to be C: I don't know if you have to format SSDs or not but I don't think so. I have a Samsung 830 on this computer w Windoze & I didn't have to format it. I also tried installing with a Ubuntu Studio DVD which I burned @ single speed, as I had seen some warnings about disks burned faster but still no-go. This machine ran fine when it had Windoze & I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't do Ubuntu.

Can somebody help me out here???

Erik The Pope

Comment: How much RAM does your laptop have, processor speed? Have you tried a USB?

Comment: Not a laptop. ASUS P5E3, 3 GHz chip, 4 GB ram, EVGA Force 8800 GTX video, Intel SSD. I haven't tried installing via USB so I guess that's on the agenda for today/tomorrow. Got a band gig today so it might have to wait 'til tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was the real problem but I changed the mouse from a Logitech USB to a Microsoft Bluetooth and voila! Everything that didn't work before now works.

I hate computers...

Erik The Pope